# How would I turn this in to a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `Job` and `Task` models where `Task has_many :jobs` and `Job belongs_to :task`.

When querying jobs, I end up doing a `join` on `task` and doing a `where` like this:

```
jobs.joins(:task).where('tasks.department = ? and tasks.number = ?', 'PW', '135')
```

So how could I add a `scope` with arguments to the `Job` model that can pull that off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
scope :scope_name, ->(arg1, arg2){ joins(:task).where('tasks.department = ? and tasks.number = ?', arg1, arg2)}
```